# Server alias for virtual host doesn't load site

Tags: apache, virtual-hosts

Here's my current virtual host setup for xampp:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot c:/misc/proj/usermap
ServerName usermap
ServerAlias usermap2

ErrorLog c:/misc/proj/usermap/logs/error_log
CustomLog c:/misc/proj/usermap/logs/access_log common


<Directory "c:/misc/proj/usermap">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The site works fine with the ServerName domain (usermap). I wanted to add an other domain which points the exact same site configuration with a different domain (so that I can do different things in the code based on the domain). That's why I added the ServerAlias line.

I have both hostnames resolve to 127.0.0.1 in the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 usermap
127.0.0.1 usermap2
```

The site works fine if I use the original usermap domain, but the browser keeps on loading if I try usermap2. It shows a blank page and "sending request to usermap2..." is in the status bar, but nothing else is happening. Is there a logfile which I could check to see why it's not working? The apache/logs don't show anything unusal.

Comment: Yes, and it loads the default xampp error page if it's not in vhosts.conf. But if I add the ServerAlias line with usermap2 as described above to vhosts.conf and restart xammp then the browser just keeps on loading and doesn't return anything. I'm baffled.

Answer (score 4):

did you try:

```
ServerAlias usermap usermap2
```